# is there any place for me to add a refresh header without causing a loop?

Tags: php, html

I have this program that is kinda like a chat app "for testing purposes"
 
It works correctly but when i send a message i have to reload to make it appear on my end. 
I tried to redefine the text in the database after i send the message but it didnt work.
 I dont want to add a refresh button (i will add just to make it easier to check for if someone wrote something) , but i want the message to appear after i write it.
 So thought to add a refresh header in `php` sadly it always said that the headers were modified somewhere before so i added it before that code with a 1 sec delay , it worked but it loops.
 Is there any place to add the refresh header or do you have a better solution?

```
<?php
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);


    $file_pointer = "../../programs/chat-database/deb570314ba42230d7f5493b57b53970/driver.sys";
    $dbc = file_get_contents($file_pointer);

?>

<form action="chat.php" method="post">
<title>Sm Chat</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylechat.css">
<head>
<div class="nazi">
    <a style="text-decoration:none" href="index.html">&nbsp; Home &nbsp;</a>
</div>
</head>

<body vlink='white' alink='white' link='white'>

<center>
<div class="cont">

<?php
    echo "<br>" . $dbc
?>

</div>
</center>
<center>

<?php
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
    if(isset($_POST['btn']))
    {
        $msg = $_POST['msg'];
        $usrfile = "usr.txt";
        $usr = file_get_contents($usrfile);
        $raw = "../../programs/chat-database/deb570314ba42230d7f5493b57b53970/driver.sys";
        $fp = fopen( $raw, 'r+');
        $messg = $dbc . $usr . " : " . $msg . "<br>";

        fwrite($fp,$messg);
        fclose ($fp);
        $dbc = file_get_contents($raw);
        $dbc = file_get_contents($raw);
        $dbc = file_get_contents($raw);
    }
?>



    <div class="input-form">
    <input type="text" value="" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Enter Your Message"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="btn" class="btn"/>



</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its best to place all `PHP` code on top of your page and your `HTML` under it.
Your `HTML` is not correct at all, always start with the `<html>` tag and add a `<head>` and a `<body>`.
I structurized your code.
You should add your refresh header as high as possible before any output is generated and also inside the `$_POST` statement to ensure no output is generated before it.
You should also remove all post values before refreshing to prevent the loop.
Take a look at this reference:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

**This is how your code should look like:**

```
<?php
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', 0);
    $file_pointer = "../../programs/chat-database/deb570314ba42230d7f5493b57b53970/driver.sys";
    $dbc = file_get_contents($file_pointer);
    if(isset($_POST['btn']))
    {
        $msg = $_POST['msg'];
        $usrfile = "usr.txt";
        $usr = file_get_contents($usrfile);
        $raw = "../../programs/chat-database/deb570314ba42230d7f5493b57b53970/driver.sys";
        $fp = fopen( $raw, 'r+');
        $messg = $dbc . $usr . " : " . $msg . "<br>";

        fwrite($fp,$messg);
        fclose ($fp);
        $dbc = file_get_contents($raw);
        $dbc = file_get_contents($raw);
        $dbc = file_get_contents($raw);
        unset($_POST); // remove all post values
        header("Location: yourpage.php"); // your refresh header
    }
?>

<html>
    <head>
       <title>Sm Chat</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylechat.css">
    </head>
    <body vlink='white' alink='white' link='white'>
       <div class="nazi">
          <a style="text-decoration:none" href="index.html">&nbsp; Home &nbsp;</a>
       </div>
       <center>
          <div class="cont">
           <?php
               echo "<br>" . $dbc;
           ?>
           </div>
       </center>
       <center>
           <form action="chat.php" method="post">
               <div class="input-form">
                   <input type="text" value="" id="msg" name="msg" placeholder="Enter Your Message"/>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" name="btn" class="btn"/>
            </form>
        </center>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot Jbadminton your help was truly awsome +1